# post_detail doesnt display image

Tags: python, django

I have a really weird problem. my index page shows image. There isn't any error, codes are here:

```
def index(request):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=1)
    return render_to_response("index.html", {"post":post}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

but my detail page doesnt display image. codes here:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = "post"
    model = Post
    template_name = "post_detail.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.next = self.request.get_full_path()
        return super(PostDetailView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["form"] = CommentForm()
        context["next"] = self.next
        context["object_id"] = context['post'].id
        context["comments"] = Comment.objects.filter(
            content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.model),
            object_id=context['post'].id, is_published=True)

        return context
```

my post_detail.html page:

```
{{ post.title }}  -----here ok!
{{ post.content }} ------here ok!
<div class="img">
    {% if post.image %}
        <img src="media/{{post.image_thumb}}" /> -----but here not ok.Why?
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

my index.html

```
{{ post.title }}
{{ post.content }}
<div class="img">
    {% if post.image %}
        <img src="media/{{post.image_thumb}}" />
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

So what is my problem, thanks for time.

Comment: Model definition please..

Answer (score 0):

firstly,make sure you have set the media dir in file settings.py conrrectly and then change your image url to:

```
  <img src="/media/{{post.image_thumb}}" />
```

you missing a slash

Answer (score 0):

You should use `{{ post.image_thumb.url }}` instead of `{{ post.image_thumb }}`.

`{{ post.image_thumb }}` implicitly calls `__unicode__` method of post, but what you want is the url attribute of image, you can get the absolute url of image with this.